# Airflow logs not loading

Tags: airflow

Upon failure of nodes in my dag, I want to see logs but the page just keeps rendering(symbol) and no logs are actually loaded.

Any other way I can check logs or correct this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a directory named 'logs' at the same location with the 'dags' directory, 
default: `/etc/airflow/logs`
In it there are directories named same with your dags, then tasks, and dates. You can look there.
example: `/etc/airflow/logs/controller/trigger/2018-12-10T17:34:19.234871+00:00`